# Countdown timer - Hide variables as they expire

Tags: javascript, countdown

looking for help with a countdown timer I have to reveal a container the page at a specific time. I'd like the "days" "hours" "minutes" to disappear when they reach zero.

Can anyone help?

```
<h3 id="demo"></h3>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("1/21/2022 11:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " day " + hours + " hours " +  minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Reserve Tickets";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, please read the [help]. Specifically [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can also read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: ... well, you'd need some kind of conditional logic in your code to check for 0 and not concatenate the value if so. You appear to know how to use conditional logic (`if (distance < 0) {`), so you could at least try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update variables only if distance > 0

```js
<h3 id="demo"></h3>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("1/21/2022 11:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  let now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  let distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance >= 0) {
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " day " + hours + " hours " +  minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec ";

  } else {

    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Reserve Tickets";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```